# UIAlertView inside viewWillDisappear is not calling clickedButtonAtIndex

Tags: ios5, uialertview

I have the following code in a class, although the alert does appear in the UI (using iOS SDK 5.0) when the view is about to disappear, the **clickedButtonAtIndex** method is never called and the app terminates with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". I validated the view does/is using my class as a delegate.

The code is on the main thread and after looking at all the other responses on this subject I fail to see why my delegate method is never called. I could use another clue folks.

```
  @interface ConnectionViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
           ....
    }

@implementation ConnectionViewController
...

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        connection = [Connection objectWithConnName:[connectionName text] host:[mtDevice text] user:[userName text] passwd:[userPassword text]];
        BOOL result = [connection test];
        if (result) {
            [[FirstViewController sharedInstance] addConnection:connection];    
        } else {
            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Connection" message:@"Failed to connect to device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ignore", @"Ok", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSLog(@"clickedButtonAtIndex: %d",buttonIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert view does not block - essentially by the time you choose an option, your view controller has seen viewWillDisappear, viewDidDisappear, and probably dealloc, meaning it doesn't exist anymore.  Assuming you're using a UINavigationController, if the idea is to prompt the user before navigating back, you should override

```
- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
{
    MyAppDelegateName* delegate = (MyAppDelegateName*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if([delegate.navigationController.topViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ExitConfirmDelegate)]) {
       if([(UIViewController<ExitConfirmDelegate>*)delegate.navigationController.topViewController shouldConfirmExit]) {
            return;
       }
       [delegate.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
}
```

in your UINavigationBar where ExitConfirmDelegate is a protocol with BOOL shouldConfirmExit.  Your view controller would implement this protocol and return 'NO' if a pending alert view is visible.  Then, when the user does click an option, simply call popViewControllerAnimated again from your clickedButtonAtIndex method.

Comment: I knew it must have had something to do with blocking, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ConnectionViewController is not released **before** the "clickedButtonAtIndex" method is called.